# @Size annotation not trimming whitespace

Tags: java, hibernate, trim, bean-validation, entity-bean

I have an Entity bean and one of its String-type properties has a `@Size` annotation as follows:

```
@PSanityCheck
@Size(min = 8, max = 8, message = "validation.servicecode_length")
@NotEmptyData
@Column(name = "servicecode")
@Field
private String servicecode= "";
```

However, if I type a string containing a whitespace in the beginning, for example " 1234567" it will accept it as input made of 8 characters. How to make it trim off the whitespace? Is there an annotation for that? The UI is made with Vaadin-framework.

Comment: a validator is done for validating. Why not trimming whitespaces before ?

Comment: Haven't found a way to do that in Vaadin.

Comment: and `@Size` is nothing to do with JPA API. It is Bean Validation API

Answer (score 2):

You can use the @Pattern annotation with a regular Expression for this

Comment: However, the leading whitespace will end up in your database, and that is probably not, what you want.

Comment: is there a way to make a regular expression to trim the leading whitespace too?

Comment: Validation is not the right Approach here. Annotations like @ Size and @ Pattern will only enforce, that the data is in the right format already and cause an exception if it is not.

The most general way to check and alter data before persistence is to implement a method with the @ PrePersist annotation in your entity and make necessary changes there.

Comment: Personally, I believe that it is cleaner, to ensure that no malformatted strings arrive at your entity bean in the business layer of your application.

Comment: I think you're right. I found a way to do that in Vaadin. Not sure if this question is helpful, though, with a answer based on Vaadin-framework.

Comment: I suggest you put your solution here as a comment for anyone who is reading this question. Have a good day!

Comment: In Vaadin you add a BlurListener onto the TextField. It is triggered before validation:
 
        textField.addBlurListener(e -> {

            AbstractTextField c = ((AbstractTextField) e.getComponent());

            if (c.getValue() != null) {

                c.setValue(c.getValue().trim());

            }

        });