# Why @NotBlank not violated when leading/trailing space

Tags: bean-validation, spring-validation

This is my validation code for a field title:

```java
@NotNull(message = "Not null")
@NotBlank(message = "Not blank")
@Size(min = 10, max = 300, message = "min 10, max 300 characters")
private String title;
```

Other validations like the presented `@NotNull` or `@Size` are working fine. Only the `@NotBlank` is passed without error message when I input `" abc xyz 123 "` (with leading/last space).

I want it to give an error when there are spaces at the beginning/end of the string.

How can I validate to avoid leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: Please add the pom file and imports for NotNull and NotBlank to the question. Think is likely related to javax.validation vs jakarta.validation

Comment: Is the input-string originating from a JSON-request? Are you using Jackson object-mapper to map the request? If so, I would suggest trimming before validation, see comments on [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447744/size-annotation-not-trimming-whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

`@NotBlank` annotation is used to check for null and empty strings (text with only white space characters).

From the documentation:

```
The annotated element must not be null and must contain at least one non-whitespace character. Accepts CharSequence.
```

For your use case, you might need to use the `@Pattern` validator. From the [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/Pattern.html) of `@Pattern` :

```
The annotated CharSequence must match the specified regular expression. The regular expression follows the Java regular expression conventions see Pattern.

Accepts CharSequence. null elements are considered valid.
```

A pattern like

```
(?=^[^\s].*)(?=.*[^\s]$).*
```

along with all your other annotations might fit what you're looking for. This pattern matches any text which does not begin with a white space and does not end with a white space.

Here's a [Link](https://regex101.com/r/K6uwHa/2) to detailed explanation for this regex if you're new to regex

Note: the documentation texts are for `javax.validation.constraints` but they're also valid for `jakarta` equivalent ones.

**Edit**
Original code modified to include this solution:

```java
@NotNull(message = "Not null")
@Pattern(regexp = "(?=^[^\\s].*)(?=.*[^\\s]$).*", message = "No leading or trailing white spaces")
@Size(min = 10, max = 300, message = "min 10, max 300 characters")
private String title;
```

Comment: Excellent answer explaining `@NotBlank` constraint and suggesting the adequate alternative `@Pattern` including a __testable regex-example__.